# In GNOME 3 shell, in applications tab I cannot see any icon. How to get it?

Tags: gnome

Earlier when I clicked on the Applications tab button from "Activities", the icons used to be listed, now I see none. I am using GNOME 3 PPA.

Answer (score 3):

Corrected the problem. Thanks to the guys at GNOME Bugzilla. I reported this problem there and they were quick to reply.

Apparently one of the `.desktop` file had wrong encoding of the file name (a stupid windows application i installed using wine).
These files are located in either `~/.local/share/applications` or `/usr/share/applications`. Upon renaming it, my application icons were back.

Again thanks to Jasper St. Pierre at GNOME.